# Meteorjs payflow intergration working on website but not on ios app

Tags: ios, reactjs, meteor, paypal, payflowlink

Im trying to integrate payflow into my application. Its working fine on website. But in ios app Im getting the following error :

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/'.
```

My code:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com">
<input type="hidden" name="LOGIN" value="my vendor ID"/>
<input type="hidden" name="PARTNER" value="my partner"/>
<input type="hidden" name="DESCRIPTION" value="Order description here"/>
<input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="amt"/>
<input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="S"/>
<input type="submit" className="btn" value="Pay Now"/>
</form>
```

I have done all the required setup on manager.paypal.com website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue . The Hosted Checkout Pages are incompatible with mobile applications. This means that even if the mobile application is able to populate the Hosted Checkout Page, the credit card information is unable to be accepted and transferred from an app. We have updated our integration to use the Payflow API without using a hosted checkout page.